# How to deckare a variable in postgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

this is my exam

```
DO $$DECLARE
 oldName varchar :='old';
 newName varchar := 'new';

BEGIN
....
END$$;
```

If I run this script get this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DO"
LINE 1: DO $$ DECLARE 

        ^
```

What I did wrong?

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you are using PostgreSQL 8.4 or older, which does not support `DO` blocks. You will need to either upgrade, or use `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` to create a PL/PgSQL function, then `SELECT function_name()` to call it.

**Always specify your PostgreSQL version in questions**.